# Close Sidemenu by Clicking in Body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I would like the menu to act like the sidemenu on [Medium](http://medium.com), when the sidemenu is open and the user clicks outside `#sidebar-wrapper`, the sidemenu closes. Right now I have to click the toggle X to close the menu.

**html**

```
<a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="toggle more navbar-brand">logo</a>
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <a id="menu-close" href="#" class="toggle">X</a>
</div
```

**some css**

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -230px;
    left: 0;
    top: -20px;
    width: 230px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    position: fixed;
    height: 120%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

#sidebar-wrapper.active {
    left: 230px;
    width: 230px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
```

**js**

```
<script> 
   // menu close function
   $("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
   });
</script>

<script>  
   // menu open function
   $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
   });
</script>
```

Comment: quick and dirty way is to add a function to body.click to try to close the menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});
$(document).click(function(){
   if($("#sidebar-wrapper").hasClass('active')){
      $("#sidebar-wrapper").removeClass("active");
   }
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/j4ST6/)

Answer (score 1):

use stopPropagation it prevent from event bubbling

```
$("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
 });

  $(document).click(function(e) {
           $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
  });
```

Comment: actually.. this makes the sidemenu appear and disappear everytime the body is clicked. here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vn84z/1/